# Flexible centered SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I want centered flexible svg that:

1. Will shkrink on parent/window width/height resize
2. Will center itself (taking all avaible space)

I've managed to make almost all, exept for some reason SVG doesn't shrink vertically on window resize less than ~100px, but if you shrink window horizontally, it's will :/

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-ellis-qnol6)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the code for your question INLINE with the question to avoid link rot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a viewport-relative unit on your SVG it will shrink, so for instance set `height: 100vh` on your svg.